# Unhide one textbox with a click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to build a webpage,where i am trying to add hotel rooms.I have textboxes for 5 rooms,now after submitting I am giving the admin an alert to add more rooms if he would want to.Now i want to function it in this way.I have created 10 textboxes in a div and hid it,now when the admin clicks a button only one text box becomes visible in the div.Then if the admin clicks again the hidden textbox next to the previous one gets visible.Can anyone help.??

Comment: Please provide your effort

Comment: I have made a button which will make the whole div visible,not one by one  using simplw javascript.But the user wants this functionality.So am a little bit stuck.

Comment: Do you want something like this. http://codepen.io/tusharbandal/full/nfbDv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only show You how to find last visible textarea:

```
var lastVisible =  $('#your_div').find('textarea:visible:last');
```

And for getting next textarea to display try:

```
var showThisTextarea = lastVisible.next();
```

The rest is up to You - You are the coder, It's Your job to create code, not ours!

Comment: I am not wanting the code sir,I am just wanting the concept.

Comment: So bind click to the button, go to the last visible textarea, find it's next sibling and trigger function show() on it :)

Comment: The same functionality can be used for textbox or I have to work with textarea

Comment: As long as You are using HTML + Javascript YES :) :D Haven't heard about something called textbox in HTML ... Only textarea :) Show me some link to how does it look. :)